# I want to create Random Receipe generator with dropdown option values, and make resaults clickable (Hyperlink to a receipe's website)

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**
What I mean by this: for example from dropdown I select lunch then the h1 section in our case:(breakfast) change to lunch and if you click to generate button it gives me a random receipe from my lunch list, and the resault for example: Chicken Piccata Pasta then I could click on the result text "Chicken Piccata Pasta" and redirect me to its receipe website eg: https://www.foodiecrush.com/chicken-piccata-pasta/

```js
const breakfastz = ["Egg mayo sandwich",
  "Full English",
  "Beancurd-bacon-cheezy waffels",
  "Beans-sausage toast",
  "Egg Bread",
  "Poached eggs",
  "Chicken sandwich",
  "Hot Dog",
  "Grilled-Cheese Sandwich",
  "Scrumbled eggs",
  "Omlette",
  "Spanish omlette sandwich style",
  "Tuna & Quinoa Patties",
  "Tuna-Sandwich",
  "Fried Eggs",
];

const soup = ["Mexican Chicken Lime Soup",
  "Tomato Minestrone Soup with Garlic Bread Croutons",
  "White Bean & Ham Soup",
  "Toasted Orzo Chicken Soup",
  "French Onion Soup",
  "Beer and Cheese Soup",
  "Spicy Asian Chicken Noodle Soup",
  "Baked Potato Soup",
];

const dessert = ["Tiramisu.",
  "Chocolate mousse in minutes.",
  "Angel food cake.",
  "Not so fried' ice-cream.",
  "Roasted strawberry crumble.",
  "Apple and butterscotch pie.",
  "Almond and date cake.",
];

const pastas = ["Four Cheese Pasta.",
  "Pasta Con Pomodoro E Basilico.",
  "Home-Style Baked Pasta.",
  "Ravioli with Coconut Milk & Lemongrass.",
  "Whole Wheat Pasta in Mushroom Sauce.",
  "Spaghetti Bolognese.",
  "Lasagna.",
];

const vegetarian = ["Vegetable Dish. Malai kofta. Northern India. India",
  "Street Food. Bhelpuri. Mumbai. India",
  "Vegetable Soup. Sayur asem. West Java",
  "Vegetable Dish. Pisto. Castilla-La Mancha",
  "Rice Dish. Arroz con coco. COLOMBIA",
  "Stew. Ghiveci. ROMANIA",
  "Relish. Chakalaka. SOUTH AFRICA",
];

const sides = ["Fresh green beans.",
  "Sautéed zucchini and squash.",
  "Fruit salad.",
  "roasted veggies.",
  "Garden salad.",
  "Mashed potatoes.",
  "White rice.",
];

const lunch = ["Homemade Hamburger Helper Cheeseburger Macaroni.",
  "Chicken Piccata Pasta.",
  "Pasta with Turkey Sausage and Peas.",
  "Instant Pot Chicken Alfredo (or Stovetop)",
  "Pasta Puttanesca.",
  "One-Pot Penne Pasta with Ground Turkey and Spinach.",
  "Cheesy Chicken and Broccoli with Whole Wheat Pasta.",
];

const getRandomNumber = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

const getRandomName = () =>
  `${breakfastz[getRandomNumber(breakfastz.length)]}`;


const setRandomName = () => {
  document.getElementById("random-name").innerText = getRandomName();
}
setRandomName();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Random recipe generator</title>
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Breakfast</h1>
    <div id="random-name"></div>
    <button onClick="setRandomName();" class="btn btn-primary" id="generate">Generate</button>

  </div>

  <p class="text-center"></p>
  <form method="post" action="random-recipes-generator" class="ajax">
    <div class="text-center marg-bottom">
      <div class="col-5 no-float center">
        <div class="options-panel padd-bottom-small">
          <div class="input-group">
            <label class="form-label input-group-label" for="genre">Food type</label>
            <select name="list" id="list">
              <option value="" selected="">Any</option>
              <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
              <option value="main">Lunch</option>
              <option value="soup">Soup</option>
              <option value="dessert">Dessert</option>
              <option value="vegetarian">Vegetarian main</option>
              <option value="salad">Salads</option>
              <option value="pasta">Pastas</option>
              <option value="sides">Sides</option>
              <option value="components">Components</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: You don't have a `</form>` closing tag, you don't do anything when changing the food-type select, you always select a random item from breakfastz, you never post the form. So your code will never work. I suggest you take it step by step: first changing the H1 when you change the select, then select something random from the appropriate array. And also think about how you load the recipes. Hardcoding them in javascript is a maintenance nightmare.